# MockRestServiceServer: how to mock a POST call with a body?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, spring-rest

I am trying to mock a POST method with `MockRestServiceServer` in the following way:

```
MockRestServiceServer server = bindTo(restTemplate).build();
server.expect(requestTo("/my-api"))
        .andExpect(method(POST))
        .andRespond(withSuccess(expectedResponce, APPLICATION_JSON));
```

**Problem:** How do I verify a request body in this setup?

I browsed through [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/client/MockRestServiceServer.html) and some examples and still can't figure out how it can be done.

Comment: Why do you want to check the request body? This is input data, which should not be verified. Is it just typo and you meant response body?

Comment: @IgorKhvostenkov it is a POST requests which means it sends a piece of data. I want to verify that the information that is sent is correct.

Comment: I don't think you are doing it right, if you are trying to verify request body, you only need to test how you create the body, not mocking the Api and test what was sent by you there...

Comment: This really does not matter if this is GET or POST. Conceptually, this is strange to test something which you manually define as correct or as wrong, but is not decided by production code. You can use approach @user7294900 has proposed, but more as narrowing the scope of your mock or having a more precise trigger, but not as verification of your production code.

Comment: @IgorKhvostenkov maybe "verify" is not the best word here. Let me elaborate. I am writing an integration test. I do not want to hit a real API from the test, instead I am mocking the API. But if I do not check a request body the mocked API will return a successful response for all requests which is something I don't want.

Comment: Ok, I've got your idea, posted example how I would do this.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use [content().string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19684297/mockrestserviceserver-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-no-inputstream-speci) to verify body:

> .andExpect(content().string(expectedContent))

Or [content().bytes](https://www.codota.com/code/java/methods/org.springframework.test.web.client.MockRestServiceServer/expect):

> this.mockServer.expect(content().bytes("foo".getBytes()))
>
> this.mockServer.expect(content().string("foo"))

Answer (score 0):

How I would do such kind of test. I would expect on the mocked server the proper body to be received in `String` format and if this body has been received, the server will respond with the proper response body in `String` format. When I receive the response body, I would map it to the POJO and check all the fields. Also, I would map the request from `String` to POJO before send. So now we could check that mappings work in both directions and we can send requests and parse responses. Code would be something like this:

```
  @Test
  public void test() throws Exception{
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    URL testRequestFileUrl = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("post_request.json");
    URL testResponseFileUrl = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("post_response.json");
    byte[] requestJson = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(Objects.requireNonNull(testRequestFileUrl).toURI()));
    byte[] responseJson = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(Objects.requireNonNull(testResponseFileUrl).toURI()));
    MockRestServiceServer server = bindTo(restTemplate).build();
    server.expect(requestTo("http://localhost/my-api"))
          .andExpect(method(POST))
          .andExpect(content().json(new String(requestJson, "UTF-8")))
          .andRespond(withSuccess(responseJson, APPLICATION_JSON));

    UriComponentsBuilder uriBuilder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl("http://localhost/my-api");

    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    EntityOfTheRequest body = objectMapper.readValue(requestJson, EntityOfTheRequest.class);

    RequestEntity.BodyBuilder bodyBuilder = RequestEntity.method(HttpMethod.POST, uriBuilder.build().toUri());
    bodyBuilder.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    bodyBuilder.contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    RequestEntity<EntityOfTheRequest> requestEntity = bodyBuilder.body(body);

    ResponseEntity<EntityOfTheResponse> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(requestEntity, new ParameterizedTypeReference<EntityOfTheResponse>() {});
    assertThat(responseEntity.getBody().getProperty1(), is(""));
    assertThat(responseEntity.getBody().getProperty2(), is(""));
    assertThat(responseEntity.getBody().getProperty3(), is(""));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

May use HttpMessageConverter can help.
according to the [document](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/HttpMessageConverter.html), HttpMessageConverter::read method can be the place that provide check the input ability.